# Converting russian characters from upper case to lower case in php

Tags: php, internationalization, case-sensitive, string-conversion

I'm trying to change the case of russian characters from upper to lower.

```
 function toLower($string) {   
 echo strtr($string,'ЁЙЦУКЕНГШЩЗХЪФЫВАПРОЛДЖЭЯЧСМИТЬБЮ','ёйцукенгшщзхъфывапролджэячсмитьбю');
 };
```

This is the function I used and the output looks something like this

> ЁЙ## ёѹ##`

Can anybody help me with this ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: data encoding is utf-8
anyways got it working. thank you very much

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
$result = mb_strtolower($orig, 'UTF-8');
```

(assuming the data is in utf-8)

Answer (score 5):

Specify the charset within the HTML and use `mb_strtolower()` to convert case:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 TRANSITIONAL//EN">
<html>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
<?
$string = 'ЦУКЕНГШЩЗХЪФЫВАПРОЛДЖЭЯЧСМИТЬБЮ' ;
echo mb_strtolower($string, 'UTF-8');
?>
    </body>
</html>
```

With the meta-tag it looks like this:

```
цукенгшщзхъфывапролджэячсмитьбю
```

Without the meta-tag it looks like this

```
Ñ†ÑƒÐºÐµÐ½Ð³ÑˆÑ‰Ð·Ñ…ÑŠÑ„Ñ‹Ð²Ð°Ð¿Ñ€Ð¾Ð»Ð´Ð¶ÑÑÑ‡ÑÐ¼Ð¸Ñ‚ÑŒÐ±ÑŽ
```

Comment: Using an appropriate `Content-Type` header is preferred above using `meta` headers (but also use the latter in case people want to save and view a page locally).